# ASP.NET Identity - Confusion about [Authorize] And RoleManager

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have been following this post on creating a custom "storage provider" for the new ASP.NET Identity system, and so far it has proven very informative;

## [Creating a custom MySQL Identity Provider](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/implementing-a-custom-mysql-aspnet-identity-storage-provider)

I am not using MySQL, I am using RavenDB - and yes, I have already looked at the available RavenDB Identity Providers out there - that isn't really my issue. My issue comes with the `IUserRoleStore<IdentityUser>` and then the `IdentityRole`, as well as `RoleStore`.

I see them get created - I even see how they access data to see if a user is in a role, etc. But then later, I just see this ..

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public AccountController : Controller { 
    /// ... etc .etc..
}
```

This is where I am getting outright lost. I have looked up dozens and dozens and dozens of tutorials on the new ASP.NET Identity system and I cannot figure out at what point something becomes associated with the `AuthorizeAttribute`. How does it know to use the `RoleStore` I made? How does it know to use the `IdentityRole` I made? What is it verifying against?

These are all things I cannot find anywhere, and it is driving me kind of batty. Everything I find keeps plugging into Entity Framework, which isn't what I want to use - and it is just that way out of the box, and they seem to stop without telling you how to make sure the `Authorize` works like you want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Authorize attribute doesn't know anything about ASP.NET Identity, or any other identity system.  It simply works with `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity` interfaces that the MVC framework sets up for you.

ASP.NET Identity uses a `ClaimsIdentity` object, which implements `IIdentity`.

So the Framework, via the UserManager creates an authentication ticket.  When a page loads, it loads this authentication ticket, decrypts it, and creates the necessary principal and identity and role objects.

Then, the Authorize attribute just basically checks `User.IsInRole("Blah")` when you say

`[Authorize(Roles="Blah")]`

Comment: @Ciel - Well, I wouldn't say "literal", and if you understand the MVC (or asp.net for that matter) pipeline then it makes sense.  The key point to understand is that Authorize doesn't care about which identity system you use, it's generic to ASP.NET's builtin interfaces.  The "magic" happens in how the identities are wired up on the page load.

Comment: Lol, I was being a bit sarcastic. It does seem a bit magical though.

Comment: Man, after exploring this further, the whole thing is just amazing. Say what you will about Microsoft, and people bash them a lot - and many bash ASP.NET, but the entire strategy for the identity system is pretty incredible.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually a little bit simpler than that. When a user logs in, these lines in the `AccountController` creates a `ClaimsIdentity` and the auth middleware sets a cookie...

```
var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
```

The roles information is read from the database when the `ClaimsIdentity` is created. The identity (including the roles) is serialized and encrypted into the cookie. On subsequent requests, the `ClaimsIdentity` is decrypted and deserialized from the cookie by the middleware. The identity is attached to the thread, and that's what the `AuthorizeAttribute` uses to determine if the user is in a role. You can also programmatically access the `ClaimsIdentity` using `User.Identity` in a controller.

Comment: Man, I don't know how you guys keep up with all of this. I read every blog I can and all of this still goes so far over my head, even with all of my experience.

Comment: @Ciel - It helps to use something like Resharper or similar to reverse engineer the code and walk through it.. or look through the aspnetwebstack sources on codeplex.